# How to use PUT to update something in Vue using Django REST framework

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I am new to Vue but have experience with Django. I am using this boilerplate from Github: https://github.com/gtalarico/django-vue-template

I really like the structure of that boilerplate because it is not overwelming at all and not a lot of code is written to succesfully interact with the back-end API of Django.

It has GET, POST & DELETE already pre-installed and connected to Django REST. So far so good. However I try to add a PUT method to it so I can update models. I try to follow the same structure but I can't get it to work.

**My productService.js:**

```
import api from '@/services/api'

export default {
  fetchProducts() {
    return api.get(`products/`)
              .then(response => response.data)
  },
  postProduct(payload) {
    return api.post(`products/`, payload)
              .then(response => response.data)
  },
  deleteProduct(proId) {
    return api.delete(`products/${proId}`)
              .then(response => response.data)
  },
  updateProduct(proId) {
    return api.put(`products/${proId}`)
              .then(response => response.data)
  }
}
```

The updateProduct is the new code I added.

**Then in store --> products.js:**

```
const actions = {
  getProducts ({ commit }) {
    productService.fetchProducts()
    .then(products => {
      commit('setProducts', products)
    })
  },
  addProduct({ commit }, product) {
    productService.postProduct(product)
    .then(() => {
      commit('addProduct', product)
    })
  },
  deleteProduct( { commit }, proId) {
    productService.deleteProduct(proId)
    commit('deleteProduct', proId)
  },
  updateProduct( { commit }, proId) {
    productService.updateProduct(proId)
    commit('updateProduct', proId)
  }
}

const mutations = {
  setProducts (state, products) {
    state.products = products
  },
  addProduct(state, product) {
    state.products.push(product)
  },
  deleteProduct(state, proId) {
    state.products = state.products.filter(obj => obj.pk !== proId)
  },
  updateProduct(state, proId) {
    state.products = state.products.filter(obj => obj.pk !== proId)
  }
}
```

Here again I added updateProduct.

**Then in my Products.vue:**

```
......
<b-tbody>
      <b-tr v-for="(pro, index) in products" :key="index">
        <b-td>{{ index }}</b-td>
        <b-td variant="success">{{ pro.name }}</b-td>
        <b-td>{{ pro.price }}</b-td>
        <b-td>
            <b-button variant="outline-primary" v-b-modal="'myModal' + index">Edit</b-button>
                <b-modal v-bind:id="'myModal' + index"   title="BootstrapVue">         
                    <input type="text" :placeholder="pro.name" v-model="name">
                    <input type="number" :placeholder="pro.price" v-model="price">
                <b-button type="submit" @click="updateProduct(pro.pk)" variant="outline-primary">Update</b-button>                
            </b-modal>           
        </b-td>
        <b-td><b-button @click="deleteProduct(pro.pk)" variant="outline-primary">Delete</b-button></b-td>
      </b-tr>

.....

<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: "Products",
  data() {
    return {
      name: "",
      price: "",
    };

  },
  computed: mapState({
    products: state => state.products.products
  }),
  methods: mapActions('products', [
    'addProduct',
    'deleteProduct',
    'updateProduct'
  ]),
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('products/getProducts')
  }
};
</script>
```

Everything works fine except the PUT action to update a product. I figured that you have to use the ID of a product to be able to edit it with PUT. So that's why I used the same snippet as DELETE. But right now I am still deleting it instead of editing.

I also used now placeholder to display the text of a product entry, which is also not the correct way.. I want to use the modal to edit a product entry and then update it.

Can someone point me in the right direction?